# Some questions about downloading big data to the phone

Tags: android, download, directory, sd-card

I'm working on an application with a lot of sounds and images.. the sound (optional) can be as big as 400mb!, So I have a few questions:
1.In my Samsung Galaxy S, there is the internal sdcard that comes preinstalled within the phone and cannot be removed which is 8gb, and the external one you optionally put... 
 How can I get the location of that sdcard (which is in "/mnt/sdcard/external_sd/" and Environment.getexternalstoragedirectory() returns "/sdcard"  ?
2. I need to download a folder that have inside it a lot of folders.. I've seen some examples that download files from URL .. What about folders?
Thanks.

Comment: Please look for security issues! Is your program really allowed to use the sd-card?

Comment: 400mb of data for a smartphone app? Yikes.

Comment: @wegginho      Can you please explain more? I didnt get what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google announced that as of June 2011, the Market will support apps of up to 4GB (well, 4GB + 50MB) in size, which should be large enough to house you application files.
From user side they will have just to download the app once. But if you update you application quite often, then the updates will be very painful.
I have application that have some initial bundle and updates are downloaded into SD Card.And I have no complains from users.
Why not just to bundle all together.

Comment: Can you please explain more on what you mean by Bundle? Do you mean I should put all my audio etc into the apk and upload it to the market?