# Whats the best/noob-proof way to have large data for an application in the phone?

Tags: android

I have an application that uses pictures, audio and some text from .txt...
The size of the data that is vital for the application to run is 60 mb, but there is other optional audio that can reach up to 300mb of size!
my app is going to be published in the Android Market, So I was wondering whats the best way to make downloading the data easy for the user, here are the options I thought:

1. Make the application on the phone download .. This forces the user to keep the phone in WiFi to download ~300mb of data
2. Make a separate application that runs on the PC that manages the downloads and downloads the files to the phone while the phone is mounted on the pc ...   This forces the user to connect the phone to the PC
3. Let the user take care of downloading the files from the server and put them on the phone

Which one of these options should I go with? Is there other options? Thanks.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055988/some-questions-about-downloading-big-data-to-the-phone

Comment: @Raoul         Here I'm asking about efficiency etc.. not HOW to download..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that best way would be providing an Android Market app that will **download all the additional data during first run**. You make a dialog that will inform your users that there is going to be a lot of data download and that WIFI connection is preferred (many people have 3G with no limit).

This will allow people to download your app from market in a reasonable time. Process will be automatic  and easy for end-users.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go is with deployment of the basic app and then let the user download the content either by his choice(wifi only or mobile+wifi) and you can also provide a way to track the progress or even choose the items he wants to download from a preference list or something like that. if it was me i would never add an application that large on the market and syncing with a pc i dont think is a good idea. maybe you can have a webpage where the user can go on his pc to download the data (maybe send him the link via email or something) and then have a simple tutorial how to add it to the phone (when the phone is connected via usb to the pc - like a mass storage device).

but these days i dont think 300 mb will be an issue for most people to download so you can surely use only mobile download.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Google APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)**  for downloading more data resources for app!